# How to get the plain password from the password field in the signup form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, passwords

I have the sign up form in django through which I am taking the entry for the new user. The data can be saved using the `u_form.save` method but I also need the plain password that the user has entered as that password will be needed to create account in other website through the REST API and hence both password needs to be same. I am able to access the password from the form but when I receive it Django has already encrypted it. How can I get the original plain password?

This is what I have tried :

**views.py**

```
from users.forms import SignUpForm, ProfileForm
def create(request):
    context = {}
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        u_form = SignUpForm(request.POST) # fill it with user details
        p_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            user = u_form.save()
            email = user.email
            username = user.username
            first_name = user.first_name
            # Accessing plain password
            password = user.password
            Profile.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
            profile = p_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account Created')
            # LOGIC TO CREATE MANTIS ACCOUNT THROUGH THE REST API WITH SAME USERNAME AND PASSWORD AS OF MY DJANGO WEBSITE
    return render(request, 'mainapp/homepage.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,
                         label='Email',
                         error_messages={'exists': 'Oops'},
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
    username = forms.Field(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
    first_name = forms.Field(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))

    readonly_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "first_name", "email", "password1", "password2")




class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    emp_type = forms.Field(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
    pay_type = forms.Field(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['pay_type', 'emp_type', 'contact', 'whatsapp', 'gender', 'avatar']
```

In the views.py `password = user.password` here I am trying to get the password but it gives me the encrypted one and not the plain password. Is there any way to achieve this?

**Note :**  I know about the security threat in order to achieve this. I just want to know how can I achieve this?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. *How* are you intending to use that password?

Comment: I need that password to create a mantis account through the REST API

Comment: But why? How will you then access that account once you've created it, if it's based on a password you're not storing?

Comment: that password will be remembered by the user who is signing up

Comment: the logic is inside the views to create the account for mantis

Comment: @DanielRoseman just tell me can it be done, can I access the plain original password

Comment: Of course you can, you can use `u_form.cleaned_data['password']` just like with any other field.

Comment: Make it an answer, so that it can help other people too

Comment: @DanielRoseman One more question, lets keep the password field aside. If using dot operator and `.cleaned_data` both gives same results that is the data that was validated by the django form, then what was the purpose of creating this extra object `.cleaned_data` by the django team

Comment: I don't understand the question. `cleaned_data` is an attribute of a form that contains, well, the cleaned data. Model forms additionally have a `save` attribute that uses that cleaned data to create a *model instance*, which I think is what you mean when you talk about "dot operator". Note, you *cannot* use the "dot operator" on the form itself to access the data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman oh yes, I got confused, thank you so much BTW

Comment: @DanielRoseman its a bit off topic I know, but can you please suggest me how can I dive deeper into the django frameworks. I want to understand how this library is built, how it has been coded the ins and outs of django. Basically I want to contribute to the Django community. So where can I learn about it and what prerequisites are needed. Please help I really want to become "The Django developer" while contributing to our Django community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Daniel Roseman reply, Yes we can access the plain password field using the `.cleaned_data attribute`. Here is how you would do it.

```
password = u_form.cleaned_data['password']
```